# Java implementation for LDPC codes

Tags: java, error-correction

Is there any open source Java implementation for LDPC (Low Density Parity Check) codes, I found only MATLAB codes.

My scenario is I will take text file and divide into block and I will delete some data in text file, and by using LDPC codes I need to recover data from text files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this but the code here should get you started
http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~radford/ftp/LDPC-2006-02-08/install.html
http://www.cs.utoronto.ca/~radford/ftp/LDPC-2006-02-08/examples.html

It's in C though. Might be easy to port. Or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into ways of calling matlab functions in java.  I know there are a couple.  Also why LDPC?  While its one of the best FEC, it involves lots of matrix manipulation if I recall correctly.  This is stuff much better suited for mat[rix]lab.  The right tool for the right job...

Comment: with the help of mat lab how can i implement above scenario(Text files)

Answer (score 0):

There are also these two pure Java implementations:

- https://github.com/a4a881d4/ldpc-java
- https://github.com/pierroweb/LDPC-correcting-codes

I haven't tested them and would appreciate feedback from anyone else that has.

There's also a Java wrapper around a C++ library: http://cpham.perso.univ-pau.fr/MULTICAST/Java_wrapper_for_LDPC.html

Not the most promising results, but something to start from, at the very least.